# I want to merge same value in table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have same value in this **`<td>{{key}}</td>`** so i don't want to display again and again i want to merge it in single [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhWam.png)

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key, val) in myctrl.dep">
   <tr ng-repeat="(key_data, val_data) in val">
   <td>{{key}}</td>
   <td>{{key_data}}</td>
   <td>{{val_data.no_of_transaction || 0}}</td>
   <td>{{val_data.total_amount || 0}}</td>                                         
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

How to achive this

Comment: use `colspan`, you will have to calculate the occurrences of `{{key}}` and have `colspan` only for the first occurrance

Comment: how can check same value or not

Comment: thats the code logic you will have to write...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the child `ng-repeat`, you have same value for `key` it seems. You can make use of [`rowspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) like this to achieve it:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key, val) in myctrl.dep">
   <tr ng-repeat="(key_data, val_data) in val">
   <td ng-show="key_data === 0" rowspan="{{val.length}}">{{key}}</td>
   <td>{{key_data}}</td>
   <td>{{val_data.no_of_transaction || 0}}</td>
   <td>{{val_data.total_amount || 0}}</td>                                         
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Notice that we will only show that for first (using `key_data === 0` which is your `index`). And, we `rowspan` it till the length of child `ng-repeat`.

Comment: can you please explian bcz i want to set some other td also

Comment: @Dev sure, so `rowspan="x"` is an attribute which tells your `td` to expand till `x` rows. And, doing so only for first item in the list using `key_data === 0` for the length of inner list.. that will do your job